# Should I break down a date field into month, day, and year in core data to easily group and fetch date by month and year?

Tags: swift, core-data

How do I perform an equivalent of SQL extract/fetch records by month and year from a date in swift?

Two requirements are as follows: 
**List records by Month and Year**

1. September 2015

   October 2015

**Display transactions falling under the Year and Month.**

Edit: I do mean core data.  Rephrased "equivalent in SQL" to equivalent of SQL" to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

CoreData will store dates as doubles, which is the internal format for `NSDate`.

If you have a small database, just store the values as `NSDate` and filter based on that.

However, if you have a large database, you may want to denormalize your data a bit more.

You could store another field, say in "yyyymmdd" format, which gives you most of the filtering you require.

For finer grained control, you can also keep separate attributes for year, month, and day.

You may want to setup those fields as indexes as well, if you do lots of searching over vast amounts of data.

Remember, CoreData uses SQLite under the hood for most databases, but it's behavior characteristics are very different.

There is no universal "best" way, as it depends entirely on your data and how you use it.